# Asterisk in function type

Tags: c++, function

I found some code online for a [C++ Chat Server](http://www.taywils.me/2014/11/15/boostchatclient.html). And in the code below contains something I don't get

```
string* buildPrompt()
{
// Code for chat server
}
```

What is that asterisk after `string`? If I remove it, will the code stop working?

Comment: Yes.... `string` and `string*` are not the same thing. You should go learn C++ though.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I learned c++... But I don't remember the tutor saying anything about the asterisk after the type.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks...

Comment: "I learned C++" is a huge over-statement here. It takes a long time to learn C++ thoroughly, and if you're stumbling over what a pointer is you need to take a more humble approach here: You clearly didn't learn C++. Get [The Book on C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) written by the language's creator, read it cover to cover, and once you understand everything in it you will have *started* to learn C++. Don't ever forget that C++ is extremely unforgiving and it will punish you severely for innocent mistakes.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the link... But there is other sources to learn C++

Comment: That book is an essential tool. There are others that no doubt help with your learning, but without the official reference you're going to be working with an incomplete picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asterisk after the `string` means that it is a pointer to a `string` object somewhere else in memory. Removing the asterisk changes the return type from the function:

```
string* buildPrompt();  // <-- Returns pointer to a string.
string buildPrompt();   // <-- Returns an instance of a string.
```

I would recommend doing some basic reading on pointers in C++, they're pretty fundamental to the language once you advance from simple "Hello, World!" programs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk, in your example, binds to the return type, and indicates that, the function returns a pointer to a string instance.

If you removed the asterisk it would mean that you were returning a string instance by value.

So the asterisk indicates that the type is a pointer to whatever type it is connected to, so `int*` is a type that is a pointer to an `int`, while `int**` is a pointer that is a pointer to an `int`, and so on.

To access the string instance returned as a pointer you would have to dereference it by either prepending the return value with `*`, or accessing the members using the "arrow operator" (`->`). So the code:

```
string* str = buildPrompt();
cout << *str << endl;
cout << (*str).c_str() << endl;
cout << str->c_str() << endl;
```

Will output the same text three times, in the first example we derefence the class and output the value in it, by passing the dereferenced pointer to the `operator<<` overloaded operator for `string` on `ostream`. In the second example we dereference the pointer first, and access the call the member function `c_str` on that instance. The third example does the same, but using the "arrow" operator.

Remember that a pointer can be null, in which case dereferencing it will get you into trouble. So you should always check if the pointer is [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) before dereferencing it.